# How to set and retrieve data using set method

Tags: java

I have class Date and class DateTest. I'm trying to get the user to input the date and I have to format it properly using get/set methods and a constructor. When I try to retrieve the date after the input however, I only get zeroes.

My Code:

```
public class Date
{

private int month;

private int day;

private int year;

    public Date(int m, int d, int y){
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;

    }

        public void setMonth(int Month) {

        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getMonth(){

        return month;

    }


    public void setDay(int Day) {

        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getDay(){

        return day;

    }


        public void setYear(int Year) {

        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getYear(){

        return year;

    }

    public String displayDate(){

        return String.format("%d / %d / %d", month, day, year);
    }


}
```

And the DateTest class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateTest

{

public static void main( String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Date myDate = new Date(0, 0, 0);


    System.out.println("Please enter the month:");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    myDate.setMonth(month);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Please enter the day:");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    myDate.setDay(day);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Please enter the year:");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    myDate.setYear(year);
    System.out.println();



    System.out.printf("The date is %s%n", myDate.displayDate());



}
}
```

And here is my output:

> Please enter the month:
>   3
>
> Please enter the day:
>   10
>
> Please enter the year:
>   2016
>
> The date is 0 / 0 / 0

It shows up as only zeroes. I'm sure it's a simple solution but I cannot grasp it.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void setYear(int Year) {
   this.year = year;
}
```

Java is case-sensitive. `Year` is different from `year`.

What you are doing here is just assigning `this.year = this.year`.

Change the name of the parameter signature to `int year` (which is also in line with the usual naming convention of starting with lower-case letters).

All three setters have the same issue.

Comment: So as `Month` and `Day`.

Comment: I knew it was something simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Replace `this.month = month;` with `this.month = Month;`
- Replace `this.day = day;` with `this.day= Day;`
- Replace `this.year= year;` with `this.year= Year;`

Hope you got the problem, you need to assign the member variable to that is passed in argument, not the member variable assigned to itself.

```
public void setDay(int Day) {

    this.day = day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you pass in the following: `public void setMonth(int Month)`,  `public void setDay(int Day)`, `public void setYear(int Year)`, **must agree** with where you refer to the parameter, for example `this.day = day;` must be `this.day = Day;` in this case. This means the names must be typed exactly the same, or you're referring to `day` twice, thus not changing its value but referencing and setting it to its default value, `0`. So essentially, it is just a matter of understanding which variable name to place on the right side of the `=`. However, Java programming does have naming conventions which you may want to take a look at [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). But here is a quick rundown:

[image: A table displaying the basics of Java naming conventions]
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ0tb.png) for the larger image.